# HTML input placeholder passing in some invisible value

Tags: php, html, placeholder

So I have a form where one entry is:

`<input name="curr_loc" type="text" placeholder="Default" >`

and upon submitting the form without entering anything into this particular input entry,
somehow `$_POST['curr_loc']` is not `NULL` and contains some invisible value as 
  `isset($_POST['curr_loc'])` is found to be `TRUE`. I tried printing this out, and it's `TRUE`. Why is this so?? (Every other field is working fine).

Comment: What are you expecting instead?

Comment: The field is present in the form that's submitted - so it's true that the `$_POST` array key exists, even if the value is empty.

Comment: Forms _never_ send `NULL` (well, type=text's), they send empty strings on no input, which means `isset()` would indeed just return true.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have misunderstood the differences between [**NULL**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php)  & [**isset()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

In given form that looks like this:

```
<form method='POST'>
<input name="curr_loc" type="text" placeholder="Default" />
<input type='submit' />
</form>

<?php
    var_dump(@$_POST['curr_loc']);
```

When you submit a post it will give you

`string '' (length=0)`

Which basically means, that a form is submitted, and **since** all form submission are interpreted as a `string` however, in this case the `0` indicates, that the value was `0` in **length**.

One the other hand [**NULL**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) represents a *variable* who's values are non-existent. Or a variable with no values.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, all text boxes in submitted forms which are empty will have the value "" (empty string). The reason that isset returns true is because the variable actually exists, it just has an empty string value.

If you want to check for variables being set in a form, you should use `if ($_POST['curr_loc'] != "")`.